# Blender 2.8 modifier apply Python

Tags: python

has somebody an idea how to apply a modifier with Python in Blender 2.8 or is it just a bug and not an API / internal change?

When I apply like this:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bool_mod.name)
```

which works with 2.79 I get this error in 2.8:

> File ".... blender-2.80.0-git.421017d24a0-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py",
>   line 192,  in **call**
>           ret = op_call(self.idname_py(),  None, kw) RuntimeError:  Operator bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply.poll() Context missing
>   'modifier'

Comment: Sorry I can't help you but only can tell you I'm stuck in a similar situation. I also have the same question you have, among many 2.8 Python questions. If you or others happen to find a good resource please link it here!

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed now, was just missing in Blender 2.8 at the time I added this issue.

Comment: thanks for letting us know. I'm still voting to close the question, as it was about a Blender 2.8 bug and is no longer valid.

Comment: ok, thx. I used this here in my addon fast carve, here is the module in which I am using it: https://github.com/jayanam/fast-carve/blob/fast-carve-2-8/fc_bool_util.py